# Passing an object to MVC controller method in AJAX success using window.location

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Ajax call -

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: configMap.sitePath + "api/Quiz/" + quizResponse.quizId,
            data: JSON.stringify(quizResponse),
            success: function(data) {
                var resultid = data.data.quizInstanceId;
                var resultresponse = data.data;
                window.location.href = "supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/" + resultresponse;
            }
```

controller Method -

```
   public ActionResult ScptResult(QuizResult resultresponse)
    {
         // Do something
        return View();
    }
```

Route -

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SupplyChainPressureResult",
        //url: "supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/{resultid}",
        url: "supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult/{resultresponse}",
        defaults: new { controller = "SupplyChainPressure", action = "ScptResult" }
        );
```

class -

```
public class QuizResult
    {
        public int quizInstanceId { get; set; }
        public string WeakestLinkCode { get; set; }
        public string WeakestLinkDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal PercentageOfUsers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<OverallResult> OverallResults { get; set; }
    }
```

But For some reason the `resultresponse` is null in the controller method. Can someone help please . We need to pass `data.data` (`resultresponse`) to the controller Method.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan quizresponse  is fine. I could see the values in the quizresponse.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question. I thought you were having issues in the request, not the response.

Comment: No Problem . Can you see what might be the issue in the response

Comment: What is the data being returned from `ScptResult`?

Comment: if `data.data` already has additional object properties as in `resultId` then you can't concatenate `data.data` and a string

Comment: Try adding the HTTP attribute to your controller method?

Comment: @Mark  should it be [HttpPost] ?

Comment: @NitinKumarMishra yes, should be `[HttpPost]`. And you can make route `url: "supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult"`

Comment: @adricadar the redirection doesnt happen now - window.location.href = 'supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult' + resultresponse;    url: "supply-chain-pressure/ScptResult",     [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ScptResult(QuizResult resultresponse)
        {

Comment: What you try to do it's a little 'nasty', you have to do another ajax post to that method, and in succes to make an redirect by id.

Comment: What is the value of `data.data`? (you need to show the controller method for `api/Quiz`) You cant append a complex object to your url as a query string. And what is the point of using ajax if your just wanting a redirect anyway?

Comment: @StephenMuecke data.data is a complex object . I need to redirect to a new page with data.data . Can some one suggests another way of doing it. I can make another call to api/quiz

Comment: You should not pass a complex object to a GET method (apart from the ugly query string, it could exceed the query string limit and throw an exception, and if the model contains properties which are complex objects or collections it will fail anyway). There is no point in using ajax if you want to redirect. Just do a normal submit, and in the controller do a `RedirectToAction()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Every one for the Help . I only using one parameter and then redirecting to a controller methods which does the stuff for me -

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: configMap.sitePath + "api/Quiz/" + quizResponse.quizId,
                    data: JSON.stringify(quizResponse),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var resultId = data.data.quizInstanceId;
                        window.location.href = configMap.sitePath + 'Result-Display/Index/' + resultId;
                       },
```